# Get songs from playlist

Tags: python, html, django, web

Here is my Playlist model

```
class Playlist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False, default='')
    songs = models.ManyToManyField('Song')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def playlist_id(self):
        return self.id
```

It works fine, but how do I get the songs from the playlist?

Comment: `my_playslist = Playlist.objects.get(name='my_playlist')` and then `my_playlist.songs.all()`.

Answer (score 0):

Once you already got a playlist intance, you can do:

```
playlist.songs.all()
```

Or you could filter if you need to meet some criterion:

```
playlist.songs.filter(name__in=['song name 1', 'song name 2'])
```

Refer to [the Django documentation on object retrieval](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-objects) for all the possibilities.